# kernel density with weighted observations in r

Tags: r, 2d, kernel-density

I have coordinates of road accident data and I want to use 2d kernel density with weighted observation by severity of accident:
For example, I want fatal accident to be counted 3 times and damage only accident to be counted 1 time. How do I add it to the function? I notice that w in the function means that weights have to sum to sample size.
Thank you!

Comment: kde(a[,1:2],w=numeric(length(x))+3), lets say all of the accidents are severe and I want them to be counted 3 times. only this works:kde(a[,1:2],w=numeric(length(x))+1). sum of w has to be sample size

Comment: Can you post a minimal example please.

Comment: a=cbind(c(1,2,5,6),c(3,4,6,2)). coordinates of severe accidents

Comment: Which package are you using?

Comment: im using ks package

Comment: Ok so in a object you have provided, how do I know which is a fatal accident compared to a non-fatal accident?

Comment: Doesnt really matter. lets say the first 2 are fatal and the other 2 are damage only. How do I count the fatal ones 3 times?

Comment: By providing a vector of weights which correspond to your training examples (usually). Your training data will be labelled, therefore it should be easy to create a vector of the same length.

Comment: w=c(3,3,1,1) for example? In kde function the sum of w has to be equal to sample size which is 4. but here sum(w)=8.

Comment: On a default model, check the length of the weights vector. By default the weight vector is filled with 1's. I feel you may be getting confused with the length of the weight vector must equal the number of data points in your training data.